# Need help by mapping a array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have this Array with 6 different dates from db:

```
[{"_id":{"source":"2019-04-06","status":false},"count":1},
{"_id":{"source":"2019-04-06","status":true},"count":1},
{"_id":{"source":"2019-03-24","status":false},"count":2},
{"_id":{"source":"2019-03-24","status":true},"count":1},
{"_id":{"source":"2019-03-23","status":false},"count":3},
{"_id":{"source":"2019-03-08","status":false},"count":1},
{"_id":{"source":"2019-02-02","status":true},"count":1},
{"_id":{"source":"2019-02-02","status":false},"count":2},
{"_id":{"source":"2019-01-29","status":false},"count":1}]
```

What i need are 2 Arrays with the length of 6 items and the value of "count" 
If only status "true" exists for a date, then i need to push a count: "0" to the false-array.
And if only status "false" exists for a date, then i need to push a count: "0" to the true-array.

It should look like this:

```
Arrayforstatusfalse = [1,2,3,1,2,1]
Arrayforstatustrue = [1,1,0,0,1,0]
```

But what i get is this:

```
Arrayforstatusfalse = [1,2,3,1,2,1]
Arrayforstatustrue = [1,1,1]
```

Update:
Sorry for this ugly code. i will be more precise. And thanks for your help.

```
this.responsedata = input  
this.line1 = output for all the "false"
this.line2 = output for all the "true"
```

I loop over input data with condition and push it into the new arrays:

```
  for (var i=0; i<this.responsedata.length;i++) {
       if (this.responsedata[i]._id.status === true ) {
          console.log('true exits for date: ' + JSON.stringify(this.responsedata[i]._id.source) + JSON.stringify(this.responsedata[i].count) )
          this.line2.push(this.responsedata[i])
       }
       if (this.responsedata[i]._id.status === false ) {
         console.log('false exits for date: ' + JSON.stringify(this.responsedata[i]._id.source) + JSON.stringify(this.responsedata[i].count) )
         this.line1.push(this.responsedata[i])
      }
  }
```

Console :

```
[Log] false exits for date: "2019-04-06"1
[Log] true exits for date: "2019-04-06"1
[Log] false exits for date: "2019-03-24"2
[Log] true exits for date: "2019-03-24"1
[Log] false exits for date: "2019-03-23"3
[Log] false exits for date: "2019-03-08"1
[Log] true exits for date: "2019-02-02"1
[Log] false exits for date: "2019-02-02"2
[Log] false exits for date: "2019-01-29"1
[Log] line1[1,2,3,1,2,1]
[Log] line2[1,1,1]
```

And here i need line2 = [1,1,0,0,1,0]
because i need a 0 "if not exits on this date"..

Comment: where's your mapping code?

Comment: Also, how you do you get from 9 items in the original array to 6 items each in the result arrays?

Comment: how to go from 9 to 6 items is covered in the description. Why the questioner gets the answers they got was pretty clear when I tried what I thought was the obvious solution. If you filter by true or false and print the counts you get what the questioner said they got. So the question seems pretty clear to me.

Comment: Your desired result seems not very useful: how will you know from the end result which count relates to which date?

Comment: sorry for this shit.. pls stop working.. I solved it, by re arrange the incoming array.. much easier now..

Answer (score 1):

You could take a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) for keeping the same index in insertation order of the given data.

```js
var array = [{ _id: { source: "2019-04-06", status: false }, count: 1 }, { _id: { source: "2019-04-06", status: true }, count: 1 }, { _id: { source: "2019-03-24", status: false }, count: 2 }, { _id: { source: "2019-03-24", status: true }, count: 1 }, { _id: { source: "2019-03-23", status: false }, count: 3 }, { _id: { source: "2019-03-08", status: false }, count: 1 }, { _id: { source: "2019-02-02", status: true }, count: 1 }, { _id: { source: "2019-02-02", status: false }, count: 2 }, { _id: { source: "2019-01-29", status: false }, count: 1 }],
    result = array.reduce((m => (r, { _id: { source, status }, count }) => {
        var index = m.get(source);
        if (index === undefined) {
            m.set(source, index = m.size);
            r.true[index] = 0;
            r.false[index] = 0;                    
        }
        r[status][index] = count;
        return r;
    })(new Map), { true: [], false: [] }),
    { true: trues, false: falses } = result;

console.log(...trues);
console.log(...falses);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `reduce()` to summarize the array into an object using the source as key. Convert the object into array using `Object.entries` and reduce it again to convert the inner child object into an array.

Use `destructuring assignment syntax` to assign into variables.

```js
let array = [{"_id":{"source":"2019-04-06","status":false},"count":1},{"_id":{"source":"2019-04-06","status":true},"count":1},{"_id":{"source":"2019-03-24","status":false},"count":2},{"_id":{"source":"2019-03-24","status":true},"count":1},{"_id":{"source":"2019-03-23","status":false},"count":3},{"_id":{"source":"2019-03-08","status":false},"count":1},{"_id":{"source":"2019-02-02","status":true},"count":1},{"_id":{"source":"2019-02-02","status":false},"count":2},{"_id":{"source":"2019-01-29","status":false},"count":1}];

let {Arrayforstatusfalse,Arrayforstatustrue} = Object.entries(array.reduce((c, v) => {
    c.Arrayforstatustrue[v._id.source] = c.Arrayforstatustrue[v._id.source] || 0;
    c.Arrayforstatusfalse[v._id.source] = c.Arrayforstatusfalse[v._id.source] || 0;
    if (v._id.status) c.Arrayforstatustrue[v._id.source] += v.count;
    else c.Arrayforstatusfalse[v._id.source] += v.count;
    return c;
  }, {Arrayforstatusfalse: {},Arrayforstatustrue: {}}))
  .reduce((c, [k, o]) => Object.assign(c, {[k]: Object.values(o)}), {});

console.log(Arrayforstatusfalse);
console.log(Arrayforstatustrue);
```

Comment: I think that is about the most unreadable code I've seen in my life  (not suggesting mine is any better)

Answer (score 0):

This?

```js
const data = [
  {"_id":{"source":"2019-04-06","status":false},"count":1},
  {"_id":{"source":"2019-04-06","status":true},"count":1},
  {"_id":{"source":"2019-03-24","status":false},"count":2},
  {"_id":{"source":"2019-03-24","status":true},"count":1},
  {"_id":{"source":"2019-03-23","status":false},"count":3},
  {"_id":{"source":"2019-03-08","status":false},"count":1},
  {"_id":{"source":"2019-02-02","status":true},"count":1},
  {"_id":{"source":"2019-02-02","status":false},"count":2},
  {"_id":{"source":"2019-01-29","status":false},"count":1},
];

const byDate = {};
data.forEach((f, ndx) => {
  byDate[f._id.source] = byDate[f._id.source] || [];
  byDate[f._id.source].push(f);
});

function mapCounts(byDate, status) {
  return Object.values(byDate).map(d => {
    const ndx = d.findIndex(e => e._id.status === status);
    return ndx >= 0 ? d[ndx].count : 0;
  });
}
const falseForDate = mapCounts(byDate, false);
const trueForDate = mapCounts(byDate, true);

console.log(falseForDate.join(','));
console.log(trueForDate.join(','));
```

note I'm curious what this is acutally for. The code above will not handle things if there are 3 of the same date because then there are would either be 2 counts for true or 2 for false. Which count to use. Similarly the same sitatuion arrises if their are 2 trues or 2 falses for the same date (same issue really). Maybe you want to sum the counts for true or false by date?

In that case

```js
const data = [
  {"_id":{"source":"2019-04-06","status":false},"count":1},
  {"_id":{"source":"2019-04-06","status":true},"count":1},
  {"_id":{"source":"2019-03-24","status":false},"count":2},
  {"_id":{"source":"2019-03-24","status":true},"count":1},
  {"_id":{"source":"2019-03-23","status":false},"count":3},
  {"_id":{"source":"2019-03-08","status":false},"count":1},
  {"_id":{"source":"2019-02-02","status":true},"count":1},
  {"_id":{"source":"2019-02-02","status":false},"count":2},
  {"_id":{"source":"2019-01-29","status":false},"count":1},
];

const byDate = {};
data.forEach((f, ndx) => {
  byDate[f._id.source] = byDate[f._id.source] || [];
  byDate[f._id.source].push(f);
});

function mapCounts(byDate, status) {
  return Object.values(byDate).map(d => {
    return d.reduce((acc, e) => acc + (e._id.status === status ? e.count : 0), 0); 
  });
}
const falseForDate = mapCounts(byDate, false);
const trueForDate = mapCounts(byDate, true);

console.log(falseForDate.join(','));
console.log(trueForDate.join(','));
```

or

```js
const data = [
  {"_id":{"source":"2019-04-06","status":false},"count":1},
  {"_id":{"source":"2019-04-06","status":true},"count":1},
  {"_id":{"source":"2019-03-24","status":false},"count":2},
  {"_id":{"source":"2019-03-24","status":true},"count":1},
  {"_id":{"source":"2019-03-23","status":false},"count":3},
  {"_id":{"source":"2019-03-08","status":false},"count":1},
  {"_id":{"source":"2019-02-02","status":true},"count":1},
  {"_id":{"source":"2019-02-02","status":false},"count":2},
  {"_id":{"source":"2019-01-29","status":false},"count":1},
];

const byDate = {};
data.forEach((f, ndx) => {
  byDate[f._id.source] = byDate[f._id.source] || [0, 0];
  byDate[f._id.source][f._id.status === true ? 1 : 0] += f.count;
});

const falseForDate = Object.values(byDate).map(v => v[0]);
const trueForDate = Object.values(byDate).map(v => v[1]);

console.log(falseForDate.join(','));
console.log(trueForDate.join(','));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get unique sources (dates) and create `true` and `false` arrays for each `source` :

```js
const dataArray = [{"_id":{"source":"2019-04-06","status":false},"count":1},
{"_id":{"source":"2019-04-06","status":true},"count":1},
{"_id":{"source":"2019-03-24","status":false},"count":2},
{"_id":{"source":"2019-03-24","status":true},"count":1},
{"_id":{"source":"2019-03-23","status":false},"count":3},
{"_id":{"source":"2019-03-08","status":false},"count":1},
{"_id":{"source":"2019-02-02","status":true},"count":1},
{"_id":{"source":"2019-02-02","status":false},"count":2},
{"_id":{"source":"2019-01-29","status":false},"count":1}];
// Get all sources
const sources = dataArray.map(item => item._id.source);
// Get unique sources
const uniqueSources = [...(new Set(sources))];

const arrayForStatusTrue = [];
const arrayForStatusFalse = [];

uniqueSources.forEach(source => {
  // Check if source with status true exists
  const itemWithStatusTrue = dataArray.find(item => (item._id.status && item._id.source === source));
  itemWithStatusTrue ? arrayForStatusTrue.push(itemWithStatusTrue.count) : arrayForStatusTrue.push(0);
  
  // Check if source with status false exists
  const itemWithStatusFalse = dataArray.find(item => (!item._id.status && item._id.source === source));
  itemWithStatusFalse ? arrayForStatusFalse.push(itemWithStatusFalse.count) : arrayForStatusFalse.push(0);
});

console.log(arrayForStatusTrue);
console.log(arrayForStatusFalse);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `map` to achieve this. They `key` of the map will be the `source` and value will be `count`. If no value found for a particular `key`, then assign 0. Otherwise assign value based on the given condition.

Iterate over all elements of `inputArray`. After the end of iteration, you will get two objects. Just take the values of the objects using `Object.values()` function.

You're done!!!

I have used [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) to make the code look short and easy. See the snippet below

```js
var inputArray = [{"_id":{"source":"2019-04-06","status":false},"count":1},{"_id":{"source":"2019-04-06","status":true},"count":1},{"_id":{"source":"2019-03-24","status":false},"count":2},{"_id":{"source":"2019-03-24","status":true},"count":1},{"_id":{"source":"2019-03-23","status":false},"count":3},{"_id":{"source":"2019-03-08","status":false},"count":1},{"_id":{"source":"2019-02-02","status":true},"count":1},{"_id":{"source":"2019-02-02","status":false},"count":2},{"_id":{"source":"2019-01-29","status":false},"count":1}];

var trueObjects = {},
  falseObjects = {};

inputArray.forEach(function(elem) {
  var index = elem._id.source,
    status = elem._id.status,
    count = elem.count;

  //initialize value for new index
  trueObjects[index] = trueObjects[index] ? trueObjects[index] : 0;
  falseObjects[index] = falseObjects[index] ? falseObjects[index] : 0;

  //set value based on condition
  trueObjects[index] = status ? count : trueObjects[index];
  falseObjects[index] = !status ? count : falseObjects[index];
});

trueArray = Object.values(trueObjects);
falseArray = Object.values(falseObjects);

console.log(falseArray);
console.log(trueArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using a `Map` to create one entry per date (`source`), which each would have two values representing the counts for both possible statuses (initialised with zero).

Then add the actual counts to those entries, and finally extract the data into the two arrays you expect:

```js
// Sample input
const array = [{ _id: { source: "2019-04-06", status: false }, count: 1 }, { _id: { source: "2019-04-06", status: true }, count: 1 }, { _id: { source: "2019-03-24", status: false }, count: 2 }, { _id: { source: "2019-03-24", status: true }, count: 1 }, { _id: { source: "2019-03-23", status: false }, count: 3 }, { _id: { source: "2019-03-08", status: false }, count: 1 }, { _id: { source: "2019-02-02", status: true }, count: 1 }, { _id: { source: "2019-02-02", status: false }, count: 2 }, { _id: { source: "2019-01-29", status: false }, count: 1 }];

// Algorithm
const map = new Map(array.map(o => [o._id.source, [0,0]]));
array.forEach(o => map.get(o._id.source)[+o._id.status] += o.count);
const [noes, ayes] = [0, 1].map(i => Array.from(map.values(), a => a[i]));

// Output
console.log(JSON.stringify(noes), JSON.stringify(ayes));
```